# perl: setting default, local, and global user settings

Tags: perl, module, environment-variables

I'm working on a `perl` script (`myscript.pl`) and I would like to load some environment variables from various modules  in this order:

- default settings in `defaultSettings.pm` in the same directory as `myscript.pl`
- (optional) user settings in `userSettings.pm` somewhere else that the user can choose
- (optional) local settings in `localSettings.pm` in the current working directory

I have resolved my first and last bullet, but haven't had much success resolving the second.

**`myscript.pl`**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin;            
use lib $FindBin::Bin;

# defaultSettings always present in same directory as myscript.pl
use defaultSettings;   

# localSettings sometimes present (in current working directory)
eval
{
    require localSettings;
      localSettings->import();
    };

print "Some variable is: ",$someVariable;
exit
```

**`defaultSettings.pm`**

```
package defaultSettings;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter;

use vars qw($VERSION @ISA @EXPORT);

$VERSION     = 1.00;
@ISA         = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT      = qw($someVariable
                  );

our $someVariable="default settings";
1;
```

**`localSettings.pm`**

```
package localSettings;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter;

use vars qw($VERSION @ISA @EXPORT);

$VERSION     = 1.00;
@ISA         = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT      = qw($someVariable
                  );

our $someVariable="local settings";
1;
```

I know that I could use

```
use lib "/home/foo/bar/";
use userSettings;
```

in `myscript.pl`, but I would like to avoid having users edit the `myscript.pl`- the main hope/goal is to have the users edit a file *other than* `myscript.pl`.

I'm open to other work flows that accomplish the same idea `:)`

Comment: How about making it a command line option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use Perl modules to store configuration data. It isn't what they are meant for and, as you have seen, they aren't really fit for the purpose. There is also a potential security risk in that modules contain executable Perl that could do pretty much anything to your system. Data is far better stored in non-executable files.

Instead, use something like JSON data files that can be put anywhere on the disk volume and read directly into Perl data structures.

Your main problem seems to be how to define the location of the third set of configuration data, and the option most obvious to me is that it should be specified in one of the other two sets - probably the one stored in the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches that come to mind:

- `use lib "$ENV{HOME}/bar";` if all you care about is not requiring the user to enter the path of their home directory but you can assume a particular path inside that directory.
- `use lib $ENV{MYSCRIPT_CONFIG};` if you're willing to require that users have that environment variable set (although you at least get warnings if it's not set at all, so this isn't ideal; you could instead make a `BEGIN` block that checks whether it's set and then open-codes the effect of `use lib`).

However, I would make a more fundamental suggestion: I think you're using `use` and `require` when you actually want `do`.  Rather than adding all those random paths to your global module search path, which will be used for every other module you load as well, consider a strategy like:

```
if ($ENV{HOME} && -f "$ENV{HOME}/bar/localSettings.pm") {
    my $file = "$ENV{HOME}/bar/localSettings.pm";
    my $status = do $file;
    die "couldn't parse file $file: $@" if $@;
    die "couldn't load $file: $!" unless defined $status;
    die "couldn't load $file" unless $status;
}
```

The disadvantage of `do` is much more verbose error management.  The advantage is that you don't have to add things to the module path, you don't have to name the files anything in particular, and you don't even have to use separate names for the three types of settings files in order to keep from the `%INC` handling preventing loading all the configuration.

(The other answer also has a good point in that you should always think twice about using Perl modules for configuration data, but there are some times when that's a very good idea.  One is when the user configuration can include full-blown callback functions written in Perl.  I have several software packages where that's the case.)